# I always want to display pages using the react-bootstrap-table2-paginator library

Tags: reactjs, pagination

When the component is render first time the page number is not display, when all the data is successfully come from api, then only it display the page number.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuNfv.png)

I want to display the Page number when data is still getting from Api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxagP.png)